# GROUP BY с агрегирующими функциями на LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Как делать GROUP BY с агрегирующими функциями на LINQ, используя method syntax?
Например, есть такая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
    product_code NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    partner_id INT NOT NULL,
    version INT NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (product_code, partner_id, version),
    ...
);
```

На SQL запрос выглядит так

```
SELECT product_code, partner_id, MAX(version) AS maxversion 
FROM product GROUP BY product_code, partner_id
```

Как сделать аналогичный запрос на LINQ? Т.е. есть класс `Product` с такими же полями и есть `IEnumerable<Product>`, так вот как из него получить аналогичные данные?

`Enumerable.GroupBy` возвращает какой-то `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`, с которым непонятно что делать.

Comment: `context.Products.GroupBy(p=>new{p.code, p.partnerId})`?

Comment: @tym32167, это понятно, я про то что дальше, что в `Select` передавать

Comment: Непонятно, как сделать `MAX(version) AS maxversion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так

```
Products.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductCode, x.PartnerId })
    .Select(g => new { ProductCode = g.Key.ProductCode, PartnerId = g.Key.PartnerId, MaxVersion = g.Max(x => x.Version) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте как нибудь так

```
var maxVertionedProduct = from pr in context.Products
group pr by pr.code, pr.partnerId into grpr
select new
{
  code = grpr.code,
  partnerId = grpr.code,
  maxversion = grpr.Max(x => x.version)
};
```

Comment: Это query syntax